# sandbox skype,spotify on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sandbox

I am trying to sandbox applications such as Skype/Spotify on Ubuntu 18.04.
Both are installed under snap, which limits their access to system folders (although skype is installed using '--classic' flag, which seems to circumvent this limitation to some degree).

To limit the access to home, I see currently these possibilities:

- virtual machine
- docker image
- 'fake' user on same machine (would limit access to home but not to system folders)
- (Sandbox tools like firejail seem to conflict with snap.)

VM and the extra user would require access via 'ssh -XY'. 
From here one can call the application by:

```
XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority /snap/bin/skype
```

My question is, whether the simplest solution, creating a new user with the only purpose of running these applications, would be sufficiently safe.